# Why is this simple progam, composed of nested-loops, failing to execute properly?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I tried running this Python script in V.S. Code, but it is not executing as expected.

```
teams = ["A" + "B" + "C" + "D"]
for home_teams in teams:
    for away_teams in teams:
        if home_teams != away_teams:
            print(home_teams + " vs " + away_teams)
```

Comment: What is not working, **exactly**? Note, `["A" + "B" + "C" + "D"] == ["ABCD"]`. Did you mean `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`

Comment: If you are attempting to define a list called teams, with for values inside, you're doing it wrong. Replace the + with commas. Like this: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

Comment: `for` will iterate over characters in a string so `teams = "ABCD"` would also work.

Comment: You are not using the correct syntax. The root of the issue that this question is based on is a typo. Flagging it as such.

Comment: have a look at the itertools module

Answer (score 1):

You haven't constructed the list correctly. You had to use comma instead of plus sign:

```
teams = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

Comment: Oh thank you. this is my bad, not careful.